# Call XSLT Templates with reference

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here basic XSLT question for this i need help to get an clean solution.

My XML

```
<class_list>
<students>
    <student>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Aimee</name>

    </student>
    <student>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Anna</name>
    </student>
<students> 
<tests>
    <test>
        <name>mathematics test 1</name>
        <student_id>1</id>
        <grade>A+</grade>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>mathematics test 1</name>
        <student_id>1</id>
        <grade>B+</grade>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>mathematics test 2</name>
        <student_id>1</id>
        <grade>B+</grade>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>mathematics test 2</name>
        <student_id>2</id>
        <grade>B+</grade>
    </test>
    <test>
        <name>mathematics test 3</name>
        <student_id>1</id>
        <grade>B+</grade>
    </test>
<tests>
</class_list>
```

I like to have follow result

Aimee

mathematics test 1

mathematics test 3

Anna

mathematics test 1

mathematics test 2

This is my XSL

```
<xsl:template match="students">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="student"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student">
 <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="/class_list/tests"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tests">
 <xsl:value-of select="test[student_id=?id" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test">
 <xsl:value-of select="name" />
</xsl:template>
```

my question is how I can pass or filter "tests" with the Student id [?id]

Thanks

Roman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the idea using square brackets to filter, but it's not appropriate on "value-of", use it on "apply-templates" instead like so:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/class_list/tests[student_id='1']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to filter on the current student, you can use a variable to avoid mixup the data:

```
<xsl:template match="student">
  <xsl:variable name="stud_id" select="id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/class_list/tests[student_id=$stud_id]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Haven't tested this, but it should work.
Edited just to be complete: You can filter with square brackets on "template match" too.
Edit @Ian Roberts: great idea, I wasn't aware of current()

Comment: Or just use `<xsl:apply-templates select="/class_list/tests[student_id=current()/id]"/>` and then you don't need the variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correct input, use the following **stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="students">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="student">
  <xsl:variable name="id1" select="id"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 <xsl:for-each select="//test[student_id=$id1]/name">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="test"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the **output** I get with this:

```
Aimee
mathematics test 1
mathematics test 1
mathematics test 2
mathematics test 3
Anna
mathematics test 2
```

Please note that the input XML you show is not valid XML. Make sure that all elements are correctly closed (the `students` element for instance). Also, the `student_id` element must be closed with the same tag (i.e. not `id`).

I would recommend you check your XML (and XSLT) against an XML parser or validator to avoid this.